# android socket file transfer

Tags: android, sockets

Need help... I have understood how to make server-client socket conection... It works fie... Now I want to transfer files from server to client and back.... here are my sources...

Socket server...

```
public class ServerActivity extends Activity {

private TextView serverStatus;

// default ip
public static String SERVERIP = "192.168.1.1";

// designate a port
public static final int SERVERPORT = 8080;

private Handler handler = new Handler();

private ServerSocket serverSocket;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    serverStatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.server_status);

    SERVERIP = getLocalIpAddress();

    Thread fst = new Thread(new ServerThread());
    fst.start();
}

public class ServerThread implements Runnable {

    public void run() {
        try {
            if (SERVERIP != null) {
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        serverStatus.setText("Listening on IP: " + SERVERIP);
                    }
                });
                serverSocket = new ServerSocket(SERVERPORT);
                while (true) {
                    // listen for incoming clients


                    Socket client = serverSocket.accept();
                    /////////////////////////////////
                    File myFile = new File ("/sdcard/frostwire.apk");
                    byte [] mybytearray  = new byte [(int)myFile.length()];
                    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(myFile);
                    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
                    bis.read(mybytearray,0,mybytearray.length);
                    OutputStream os = client.getOutputStream();
                    System.out.println("Sending...");
                    serverStatus.setText("sending 123.exe...");
                    os.write(mybytearray,0,mybytearray.length);
                    os.flush();
                    client.close();
                    ////////////////////////////

                    handler.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            serverStatus.setText("Connected.");
                        }
                    });

                    try {
                        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
                        String line = null;
                        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                            Log.d("ServerActivity", line);
                            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    // do whatever you want to the front end
                                    // this is where you can be creative
                                }
                            });
                        }
                        break;
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        handler.post(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                serverStatus.setText("Oops. Connection interrupted. Please reconnect your phones.");
                            }
                        });
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            } else {
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        serverStatus.setText("Couldn't detect internet connection.");
                    }
                });
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    serverStatus.setText("Error");
                }
            });
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

// gets the ip address of your phone's network
private String getLocalIpAddress() {
    try {
        for (Enumeration<NetworkInterface> en = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces(); en.hasMoreElements();) {
            NetworkInterface intf = en.nextElement();
            for (Enumeration<InetAddress> enumIpAddr = intf.getInetAddresses(); enumIpAddr.hasMoreElements();) {
                InetAddress inetAddress = enumIpAddr.nextElement();
                if (!inetAddress.isLoopbackAddress()) { return inetAddress.getHostAddress().toString(); }
            }
        }
    } catch (SocketException ex) {
        Log.e("ServerActivity", ex.toString());
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    try {
         // make sure you close the socket upon exiting
         serverSocket.close();
     } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
}

}
```

Socket Client...

```
public class ClientActivity extends Activity {

private EditText serverIp;

private Button connectPhones;

private String serverIpAddress = "";

private boolean connected = false;

private Handler handler = new Handler();
int filesize; // filesize temporary hardcoded

long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
int bytesRead;
int current = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.client);

    serverIp = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.server_ip);
    connectPhones = (Button) findViewById(R.id.connect_phones);
    connectPhones.setOnClickListener(connectListener);
}

private OnClickListener connectListener = new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (!connected) {
            serverIpAddress = serverIp.getText().toString();
            if (!serverIpAddress.equals("")) {
                Thread cThread = new Thread(new ClientThread());
                cThread.start();
            }
        }
    }
};

public class ClientThread implements Runnable {

    public void run() {
        try {
            InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(serverIpAddress);
            Log.d("ClientActivity", "C: Connecting...");
            Socket socket = new Socket(serverAddr, ServerActivity.SERVERPORT);
            connected = true;
    //////////     // receive file
            byte [] mybytearray  = new byte [filesize];
            InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/frostwire.apk");
            BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
            bytesRead = is.read(mybytearray,0,mybytearray.length);
            current = bytesRead;


            do {
               bytesRead =
                  is.read(mybytearray, current, (mybytearray.length-current));
               if(bytesRead >= 0) current += bytesRead;
            } while(bytesRead > -1);

            bos.write(mybytearray, 0 , current);
            bos.flush();
            long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
            System.out.println(end-start);
            bos.close();
            socket.close();

     //////////////////////////////       
            while (connected) {
                try {
                    Log.d("ClientActivity", "C: Sending command.");
                    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket
                                .getOutputStream())), true);
                        // where you issue the commands
                        out.println("Hey Server!");
                        Log.d("ClientActivity", "C: Sent.");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("ClientActivity", "S: Error", e);
                }
            }
            socket.close();
            Log.d("ClientActivity", "C: Closed.");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("ClientActivity", "C: Error", e);
            connected = false;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Pieces of source which are marked by "///////" don't work.... Help

Comment: Just saying "it doesn't work" is not much of a clue... Can you maybe try to explain it better? It helps us to help you.

Comment: Socket Server gives an error... As I understand something wrong is with:

Comment: byte [] mybytearray  = new byte [filesize];
                InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/frostwire.apk");
                BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
                bytesRead = is.read(mybytearray,0,mybytearray.length);
                current = bytesRead;

           
                do {
                   bytesRead =
                      is.read(mybytearray, current, (mybytearray.length-current));
                   if(bytesRead >= 0) current += bytesRead;

Comment: on the side of server and client...

Comment: OOOooops.... logcat says - 01-19 17:50:09.866: W/System.err(9051): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /sdcard/frostwire.apk (No such file or directory)

Comment: I have new error... **01-19 18:11:47.116: W/System.err(9393): android.view.ViewRoot$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.**

Comment: More details..... Using such code, my client takes file from sdcard and starts to send it... At the same time error occures in log cat... And then this file which started transferring - becomes 0 KB on SDCARD...

Comment: Is the client and server both running on the same phone? Then the server overwrites the file while the client tries to read it!

Comment: No!!! server is on HTC Desire android 2.2, client - samsung galaxy tab 1 android 2.2

Answer (score 1):

Better you replace the following your code

```
do {
               bytesRead =
                  is.read(mybytearray, current, (mybytearray.length-current));
               if(bytesRead >= 0) current += bytesRead;
            } while(bytesRead > -1);
```

with the following one

```
do {
               bytesRead =is.read(mybytearray, current, (mybytearray.length-current));
               if(bytesRead > 0)
               {
                    current += bytesRead;
               }
   } while(bytesRead > 0);
```

Then try  it

Answer (score 0):

after going through above discussion i would like to add few comments-

1. Have you added permission code for reading sdcard in android manifest file ? If not you should add following code as the server is accessing External Storage. Do for the client also to write in external storage.

```html
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

2. Else, the directory you have provided is not correct. Check the directory.
3. In the client program, you have defined file_size which is not assigned any value nowhere in the program.
4. I would also like to suggest that, the file_size in the client program should be greater than the file to be transfer and size is in byte.